# Kaminari paginate array. How to handle lot of data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, kaminari

I need to paginate 2 different models. That what I use now:

```
activity_logs = ActivityLog.for_user(@user.id)
                  .group('activity_id').not_anonymous.recent

replies = @user.posts.recently_created

@activity_logs = Kaminari.paginate_array(activity_logs + replies)
                   .page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

But it doesn't show replies because there is a lot of records of ActivityLog. So what can I do here?

Comment: What is the result you want? It seems like you want more than 0 replies to be shown on each page, and it seems like you want them to appear after the ActivityLogs. Do you want to show all of the replies? What if there are more than 20 replies? Or do you want to limit the number of replies so there's always room for ActivityLogs? What if there aren't any ActivityLogs? We need more information.

Comment: Let's say I have 1000 ActivityLogs and 1000 replies. I need to show them on one page ordered by time of creation. For example 1. ActivityLog[18:18:18] 2.Reply[18:18:00], etc.

Answer (score 1):

Kaminari doesn't know to sort your two arrays by creation date.  You'll need to do that yourself. Something like...

```
paginatable_array = (activity_logs + replies).sort_by(&:created_at)
@activity_logs = Kaminari.paginate_array(paginatable_array).page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

And yes, `paginatable_array` is a horrible choice of names. :)

Comment: I tried that, but it took a LOT of time to combine and sort arrays if there is a lot of records

Comment: It shouldn't take that long to sort 2000 records. How much data are you looking at anyway?  Your other option is to restrict the amount of data returned in your initial two queries to reduce the amount of sorting needed.

Comment: Few millions. if I reduce returned data, how can I show them all in that case?

Comment: You have an activity log that for a single user looking at recent results is a "few million" !?!?!  Something doesn't sound right??

Comment: Doesn't matter, imagine that I need to show activity for all users